# How to probe remote Services using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, telnet, netcat

I have a project that needs to detect different service ip to distinguish between *internal network or external network* access.

At the beginning, I used the following `nc` command to detect, but the company did not allow it due to security issues

```
ret=$(nc "$internal" "$port" < /dev/null; echo $?)
if [ $ret = 0 ];then
  echo "The service can be accessed through the $internal"
  using=$internal:$port
else
  using=$external:$port
fi
```

Telnet is an optional way `telnet $host $port`, but this will occupy the terminal, and my goal is to detect whether it is accessible to determine the use of the `internal network and external network`

May I ask how to modify the telnet command, or use other methods (try to be native to be compatible with most environments) to achieve detection?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: What's the wider goal, are you trying to tie this is in with an existing monitoring solution?

Comment: There are already many tools that can perform this function. `nmap` for one. Good luck.